# How to calculate CRC for ISO CAN-FD frames

Tags: python, numpy, can-bus, crc, capl

I'm working on a study about CRC in ISO CAN-FD but I'm having issues with the calculation of the actual check sequence.

First of all, I have carefully read the specification `ISO 11898-1:2015` that states how the calculation has to be carried out.

Then, I have defined a frame to try and calculate the CRC on:

[image: sequence of bits to work on]

Note that the red zeros are stuff-bits.

The same frame has been added to a CANalzyer configuration, and my CAPL script prints the FrameCRC = `0x6bd`.

I have implemented the algorithm described in the ISO document using Numpy, but my result doesn't match what CANalyzer returns.

My code is the following (it probably isn't perfect numpy-ic coding, I'm new to this library):

```py
def crc(data):
    gen_poly = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1])
    crc_reg = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

    for bit in data:
        crc_next = abs(bit - crc_reg[0])
        crc_reg = np.roll(crc_reg, -1)      # Shift one position left (1)
        crc_reg[-1] = 0                     # Shift one position left (2)
        if crc_next == 1:
            reg_new = abs(crc_reg - gen_poly)
            crc_reg = np.copy(reg_new)
    return crc_reg.copy()
```

I also thought that maybe I misunderstood the document, and `crc_reg` and `gen_poly` have to be 18 bits long. So I modified the code this way:

- added 18 bits at zero at the end of the frame, instead of 17;
- `gen_poly = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1])`;
- `crc_reg = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])` (18 total bits);

but it didn't work as well. I really can't figure out where I'm making mistakes. I've reviewed everything many times.

Edit:
as suggested by @Reinderien, I'm providing the input data and the expected output arrays:

```py
input_data = np.array([
    0,  # SOF
    1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,    # ID
    0,  # RTR
    0,  # IDE
    1,  # EDL
    0,  # RES
    1,  # BRS
    0,  # ESI
    1, 0, 0, 0,     # DLC
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,          # Byte 1
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,       # Byte 2
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,          # Byte 3
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,       # Byte 4
    1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,       # Byte 5
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,          # Byte 6
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,       # Byte 7
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,          # Byte 8
    1, 1, 0, 0,     # StuffCount + Parity
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0     # 17 bits at zero
])

expected_output = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])    # 0x6bd
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. We don't provide general debugging services. We can assist with specific issues. Please use the following references on debugging your code to narrow your problem to a specific issue. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Comment: Can you show the reference input and output you're trying to match?

Comment: ***Why*** would you want to calculate the CRC? This is already done by the CAN FD controller hardware. The application programmer need not worry their pretty head about it, just check for errors.

Comment: @Lundin I want to calculate the CRC because I'm conducting a study on a technique to reduce the probability of undetected errors. Having this script will allow me to automatically collect statistics about the standard and "enhanced" cases. Also, I don't always have access to the CANalyzer hardware so I want to be independent from it.

Comment: Ok well... I believe you should discard the stuffing bits before anything else, because they are more low level than the checksum and so the checksum can have stuffing too. For example the "17 bits to zero" is inconsistent, either you are modelling the data as it looks on the bus with stuffing bit in data _and_ checksum, or you are modelling the data as it looks once the CAN controller has discarded the stuffing bits. Currently you are doing some weird hybrid of these two methods.

Comment: @Lundin how come? The ISO specification states that dynamic stuff bits are inserted until the last bit of the data field, and the 17 bits at zero have to be added in order to perform the calculation of the CRC sequence. Additionally, in CAN-FD, dynamic stuff-bits _are_ considered when calculating the CRC... Everything I've written is stated in the official `ISO 11898-1:2015` document

Comment: You have two extra bits in your input. You repeated RES, BRS.

Comment: Your expected output cannot be what's expected. This is a 17-bit CRC, but your `expected_output` is only 12 bits.

Comment: Also in your Python code, `crc_reg` is not initialized to all zeros as it should be. You stuck a `1` in there for some reason.

Comment: "I've reviewed everything many times." Not very well though. :-)

Comment: @MarkAdler the duplicated RES and BRS are a typo during the copy-pasting on the browser, thank you for noticing.
About the expected output you're right, I should've added 5 bits at zero at the most significant positions. I'm editing the question right now. This change won't fix the results though.
The initial `1` in `crc_reg` is on purpose, the ISO specification I mentioned indicates to initialize the register that way.

Comment: The [CAN FD](https://web.archive.org/web/20151017122935/http://www.bosch-semiconductors.de/media/pdf_1/canliteratur/can_fd_spec.pdf) spec says all zeros.

Comment: @MarkAdler yes, I'm aware it does. But that spec will lead to non-ISO frames. I have set up a network in which ISO CAN FD frames are sent, and the relative document indicates a slightly different procedure than the spec you've mentioned: first of all, in `crc_reg` the most significant bit has to be `1` and the remaining bits are zero; the second difference is that the stuff count and parity bits are included in the sequence that has to be used to calculate the CRC. Non-ISO messages don't have a stuff-bit counter.

Comment: @MarkAdler P.S.: I am certain that the frames in my CANalzyer network are in ISO format because the stuff count is shown correctly. If they were non-ISO, CANalyzer documentation indicates that `StuffCount` would be set to `0`.

Comment: Ok, you're right about the initialization. With that, it gives the result you're looking for. See my answer.

Comment: @Lundin The CRC calculation does in fact include the stuff bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do *not* process the 17 bits of zeros where the CRC goes. (Just delete or comment out that line in your input.) Then your python code outputs `[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1]`.

Comment: Well, thank you very much! I don't completely understand why it works, since both Bosch and ISO specifications state that the 17 bits have to be added in order to perform the calculation. However, the results match and it's very unlikely it is a coincidence :) thank you again Mark.

Comment: Because you do in fact need the 17 zeros if you are considering the message to be a polynomial that you are dividing by the CRC polynomial (which includes the x^17 term). Then the remainder is the CRC. However that calculation is performed by the bit operations, e.g. in your Python code, processing the data bits, and only the data bits. The same number of operations are performed in either case, since the remainder is determined once you get to the end of the quotient.